# If a company advertises a solution as 20% on their web-site, will it be 20% w/w?

Tags: aqueous-solution

I am trying to buy some ammonia solution from a company and I have found the product I want but the product particulars just tell me it's 20%.  They don't say if it's 20% w/w or w/v?  Their technical support people don't reply to queries (so far).

If I order it, will it have the product particulars on the bottle?

I think I may have to just risk it and buy it and hope the label makes it clear!

Comment: They seldom sell 183% H2SO4.

Comment: It should be labeled to be compliant with proper regulations. If its w/w it should say that and if its v/v it should say that.

Comment: Thanks Harley.  I was hoping that would be the case

Comment: This is a common issue with vendors and websites. Find the particular vendor's SDS, that has the best chance of having information as to the concentration units. Anecdotally, w/v is common for vendors that aren't a focused scientific laboratory supply vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's w/v. [This table of ammonia solution densities*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://airgasspecialtyproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Density_of_Aqueous_Ammonia_Solutions_at_20-4%25C2%25BA_C_Table.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjCs4e_kafyAhWPLc0KHWT1AeYQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1Rdll_MxO-_IVPfJSbyXuC) gives a specific gravity close to 0.92 for a solution with 200 g ammonia per liter, meaning 20% w/v, and [Fischer Scientific](https://www.fishersci.fi/shop/products/ammonia-solution-20-certified-ar-analysis-d-0-92/10737514) lists their 20% ammonia solution as having a matching specific gravity of 0.92.

*Sorry for the long link. Attempting to shorten it gave me a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean a solution of [ammonium hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia_solution)?

Maybe you could get some clues by having a look at the density / melting point, etc. of the sold solution if they are available, and compare them with some information available [here](https://gestis.dguv.de/data?name=001750&lang=en). In particular, it seems that the **density** or **melting point** may be of great help, if it is given to you with a sufficient accuracy. Unfortunately, there are only few general rules about specifying a concentration in **w/w** or **w/v** (see [here](https://www.chemicals.co.uk/blog/what-do-vv-ww-wv-mean)).

Otherwise, you will have to **weight it** or **measure its melting point** once you receive it. Indeed, according to [this site](https://gestis.dguv.de/data?name=001750&lang=en), the melting point seems to be a fairly accurate mean of finding the concentration of an ammonia soliution, and it is not too difficult to measure if you have a laboratory freezer and the associated thermometer at hand.

Comment: Ammonium hydroxide is a decades old myth.

Comment: Not entirely. [Ammoniun hydroxide may form at high pressure.](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5063569) Quoting: "We show that compression facilitates proton transfer from water to ammonia in all relevant mixtures". Such modeling is done in connection with the internal structure of ice-giant planets.

Comment: @Poutnik, three decades : https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed066p310 ^^ More seriously if you have other robust sources proving your sayings, I would be interested in reading them! I must admit that I just wanted to be sure that we were talking about this very chemical species. (Since no formula was given in the question, I didn't wanted to make a misinterpretation of Naz issue)

Comment: @OscarLanzi Correction: I do not say that ammonium hydroxide cannot exist - in fact I do know it does. The myth is about considering it at usual laboratory scenarios, like ammonia solution at room pressure and temperature or even selling it as the commercial product. As less than 1% of ammonia is present in the commercial ammonia solution as ammonium. By the similar principle, $\ce{Na3PO4}$ solution could be sold as "phosphoric hydroxide", due $\ce{PO4^3- + H2O <=> HPO4^2- + OH-}$

Comment: Hello.  I meant ammonia (aq).

That website Gestis is very useful. It has the concentration I would like but again describes the concentration as 20%.  So is that 20% w/w?  There is a reference document but I couldn't find it on the web.  If it's not clear when I receive it, I could indeed freeze it and find it's melting point and use the referece materials.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It may be easier to perform titration by HCl, after dilution.